# Carousel/navbar conflict on some mobile browsers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, carousel, navbar

I'm trying to understand why there is a conflict between the carousel and the bootstrap mobile menu [in this page](http://sims88.altervista.org/navbar-issue/) and why the problem appears only on some mobile browsers (such as Safari and the default browser on Galaxy Tab 2).

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrrOT.jpg) of the mobile menu seen on Chrome (on the left) and on Safari (on the right).

On Safari, the menu seems to be empty, but in fact if I remove the whole image tags from the carousel, the menu reappears.

I don't know how to fix this "bug".

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the cause of the problem. I've changed this

```
.carousel {top: -80px;}
```

to this

```
.carousel {top: 0px;}
```

and now the menu is working fine.